# How to add azure tags array in Python

Tags: python, tags, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to add an azure tag (array) to a resource.
Problem is with an array, or list as tags, Azure SDK for python seems to allow only str.

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.azure_tags. System.Private.CoreLib:
Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: must be str, not dict

I search in Azure SDK for python documentation : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.operations.tagsoperations?view=azure-python)

Is it possible to achieve azure tags dict/array/list creation in Python?

Answer (score 0):

For now , SDK is limited to adding/updation only one tag vaule that is why it is giving error while providing array in the parameter .

I would suggest you to loop through your array and add it individually.

```
create_or_update_value(tag_name, tag_value, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)


create_or_update(tag_name, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config) 

Creates a tag in the subscription.

The tag name can have a maximum of 512 characters and is case insensitive. Tag names created by Azure have prefixes of microsoft, azure, or windows. You cannot create tags with one of these prefixes.

Parameters
tag_name
str
The name of the tag to create.

custom_headers
dict
headers that will be added to the request

default value: None
raw
bool
returns the direct response alongside the deserialized response

default value: False
operation_config
Operation configuration overrides.

Returns
TagDetails or ClientRawResponse if raw=true

Return type
TagDetails
ClientRawResponse
Exceptions
CloudError
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm a Python beginner. Fact is current client has decided to use Azure tags with arrays inside tags and he's also well with its organisation purpose. And you suggest to iterate and set them one by one as different tags, right ?

Comment: I've trieded to implement TagsOperations or create_or_update, from ResourceManagementClient, for a single tag on a single resource without success. I'm confused. Anyone would please post an example of applying a single tag on an azure resource ? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to try writing piece of code and if you are stuck , please post what options you have tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just as additions, actually inside all available Azure APIs for `Tags` includes REST APIs (for [`Tags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags) as below) and SDK APIs, there is not an API can add more than one tag at a time.

[image]

The only way is to loop to use `create_or_update_value` method in multiple operations iteratively.